# "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid" error when trying to decrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt password stored in Asp.Net Identity "Password" filed. I'm doing this way, but got error "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid". Password stored as "1000:salt:password".

```
public string DecryptPassword(string hashedPassword)
{
    char[] delimiter = { ':' };
    string[] split = hashedPassword.Split(delimiter);
    //get byte representation of string          
    byte[] hash = Convert.FromBase64String(split[2]);
    byte[] salt = new byte[SIZE_OF_SECRETKEY];
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pwdGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(hash, salt, 1000);
    RijndaelManaged _RijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
    _RijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
    byte[] key = pwdGen.GetBytes(_RijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);   //This will generate a 256 bits key
    byte[] iv = pwdGen.GetBytes(_RijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);  //This will generate a 256 bits IV
    _RijndaelManaged.Key = key;
    _RijndaelManaged.IV = iv;
    byte[] plainText2 = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, _RijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(hash, 0, hash.Length);
        }
        plainText2 = ms.ToArray();
    }
    //Decrypted text
    return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText2);
}
```

Hashing made with this code:

```
HashPassword(string password)
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] salt = new byte[SIZE_OF_SECRETKEY];
    csprng.GetBytes(salt);

    // Hash the password and encode the parameters
    byte[] hash = PBKDF2(password, salt, ITERATIONS, HASH_SIZE);
    return ITERATIONS + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Comment: I see salt and a number of iterations. What makes you think that the password is encrypted and not hashed? If it is indeed hashed, then you cannot decrypt it.

Comment: if you're storing it with the asp.net identity provider, why not use the identity provider to decrypt it?  and are you sure it's an ***encrypted*** password you're storing and not a ***hashed*** password?  You cannot "decrypt" a hashed password.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yeah :) But that gave me the answer :) Edit: No, but getting serious dejavu here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I give up, write for decrypting seems wrong (and already sent me down the wrong rabbit hole)

Comment: @andrey.shedko What makes you assume that these pieces of code fit together? The hashing code only uses PBKDF2, the supposed decryption code using Rijndael-256. So even if your hash were reversible (which it is now), these are clearly not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to decrypt a password from the ASP.NET Identity table.

These passwords are hashed, not encrypted.

A hash is a one-way operation, you cannot reverse it to its plain-text equivalent.

An encrypted password is a two-way operation, you can go back and forward between the encrypted and decrypted representation (given you have the key).